# selectmenuchange appending object list only on first event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have two selectmenus, one of which `$('#parent')` relates to certain options in the `$('#members')` menu (related through a data attribute in their HTML). I have a function to limit the choices in 'members' where they relate to the choice selected in the parent menu.

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#parent").selectmenu();
$("#members").selectmenu();

var allMembers = $('#members option'); // keep object list of all of the options for the select menu

$("#parent").on("selectmenuchange", function() {
    var someMembers = [];
    var id = $('#parent option:selected').data('id');
    allMembers.each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('parent-id') == id) {
        someMembers.push($(this))
        }
    });
    $('#members').empty().append(someMembers);
});
```

At the moment, this works, but only on the first `selectmenuchange` event - which is odd because using `console.log()` when the arrays are recreated in the function I can see that the correct have been selected each time, they just don't show in the menu on subsequent changes.

I can't figure out if this  is a problem with `selectmenuchange` or `empty().append()`

**HTML**

```
<select name="members" id="members">
    <option data-id="101" data-parent-id="1">Name1</option>
    <option data-id="102" data-parent-id="1">Name2</option>
    <option data-id="103" data-parent-id="1">Name3</option>
    <option data-id="104" data-parent-id="2">Name4</option>
    <option data-id="105" data-parent-id="2">Name5</option>
    <option data-id="106" data-parent-id="3">Name6</option>
    <option data-id="107" data-parent-id="3">Name7</option>
</select>

<select name="parent" id="parent">
    <option data-id="1">Parent1</option>
    <option data-id="2">Parent2</option>
    <option data-id="3">Parent3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you please attach your `html` too??

Comment: Difficult because the options are intially populated from an ajax request but I've added the jist of how it looks above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the `options` were changing but it wasn't reflecting in the `selectmenu` created by `plugin`. So one of the way is you **[`destroy`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-destroy)** it and `re-initialize` the `selectmenu` as below:

```
$('#members').html(someMembers).selectmenu('destroy').selectmenu();
```

**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qtytjmys/2/)**

Comment: Twenty massive thumbs up! Seems counterintutive to destroy after adding the html but thanks.

Comment: You can switch the process... i.e. `destroy` it and then add `html` and then again `re-initiate`. It doesn't matter because you are adding options to original `select` element and when you initiate the `plugin` it will create its own set of structure using `html elements` and renders with style. So it doesn't matter.. Inspect the `select` element to see what I meant.. Here is the **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qtytjmys/1/)**. Anyways Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Will come in helpful again in my project :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `selectmenu('destroy')` and re-initializing the select menu you can also use `selectmenu('refresh')`. Refreshing sounds nicer than destroying it each time.

I have updated the fiddle of Guruprasad Rao with the refresh:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtytjmys/3/)